# Concurrency: Changing a variable with unsynchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Take this `ConcurrentDouble` class definition as an example:

```
public class ConcurrentDouble {

  public double num = 0;

  public void subtract(double num) { 
    this.num -= num; 
  }

  public void add(double num) { 
    this.num += num; 
  }
}
```

Now if I did the following,

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentDouble d1 = new ConcurrentDouble();

    Thread one = new Thread(() -> { d1.add(5); }).start();
    Thread two = new Thread(() -> { d1.subtract(5); }).start();

    one.join();
    two.join();

    System.out.println(d1.num); // <-- OUTPUT
  }
}
```

We know the number starts off at `0`, and we expect it to have `0` at the end. Is it possible that the number becomes `-5.0` or `5.0`?

Comment: What if we made `num` volatile?

Comment: Wouldn't change much. += is not atomic. The write would be guaranteed to be atomic though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. `-=` and `+=` are not atomic operations. And even then, the JVM doesn't guarantee that a write to a double is atomic.

Comment: So this is impossible without synchronization?

Comment: Basically, no. The JDK has a DoubleAdder class, but it's extremely complex. Use that, but don't try defining yours. Or use synchronization, that's what it's for.

Comment: What's so complex about it?

Comment: Read it, and you'll see.